# Triangle Geometry and Circles Problem

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

I have discovered something using Geogebra and I am positive it is true. I have tried to prove and my solution works but it is extremley convoluted. I'm hoping someone can provide a simple proof of the following:

Given triangle $ABC$ with altitudes $BB'$ and $CC'$ orthocenter $H$. Let the circumcircles of $B'HC'$ and $BHC$ intersect again at point $X$. Let $AX$ hit $BC$ at a point $M$.

Show that $M$ is the midpoint of side $BC$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that the circumcircle of $B'HC'$ goes through $A$ and the circumcircle of $BHC$ goes through $A''$, the symmetric of $A$ with respect to the midpoint of $BC$. Moreover, $B,C,B',C'$ are concyclic points, hence if $Y=BC\cap B'C'$, we have that $HX$, i.e. the radical axis, goes through $Y$ (that is not crucial for our proof, but I think it is worth noticing).
Since the centre of the circumcircle of $B'H C'$ is the midpoint of $AH$ and the centre of the circumcircle of $BHC$ is the midpoint of $AH''$, the radical axis is perpendicular to $AA''$.

[image]

Since $\widehat{HXA}=\widehat{HB'A}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, $AX\perp HX$, so $AX\cap BC=AA'\cap BC$ and the claim is proved.

Comment: There are several things I don't understand about this proof.... "The circumcircle of BHC goes through A′′, the symmetric of A with respect to the midpoint of BC." Why? Also where do you use that Y is on the radical axis?

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou: $CA''\parallel BA$ and $BA''\parallel AC$, hence $\widehat{HCA''}=\widehat{HC'A}=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and so on. The concurrence in $Y$ is not really used, but I thought it deserved a mention.

Comment: I guess this is a well-known lemma right? I didn't know about it, but I know now!

Answer (score 1):

Construction: Extend AM to cut the circle BXHC at P. Join BP and join CP.

[image]

$\beta$ is the exterior angle of the cyclic quadrilateral $PCHX$. Therefore, $\alpha = \beta$.

$\gamma = \beta$ because they are the angles on the same segment of the cyclic quadrilateral $AHXC’$.

$\alpha = \gamma$ implies $AB // CP$.

Similarly, $\theta = \delta$ implies $BP // AC$

Therefore, $ABPC$ is a //gm. This means $BM = MC$