# Orthocenter and midpoint proof

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles

Let $H$ be the orthocenter of a triangle $\Delta ABC$. Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$, and let $E$, $F$ be the feet of the $B$ and the $C$ altitudes onto the opposite sides. Let $X$ be the intersection of ray $MA$ with the circumcircle of $BHC$.

Prove that

(1) $HX$, $EF$ and $BC$ concur at a point, say $P$;

(2) line $MX$ is perpendicular to the line $XH$, where $O$ is the center of the circumcircle; and

(3) also show that the line joining that point $P$ and $A$ is perpendicular to the line $HM$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You are more likely to get useful help on this site if you explain what you've tried so far, where you are stuck. Otherwise you are likely to get downvoted or have your question closed.

Comment: What and where is O?

Comment: @Mick I guess $O$ is the center of the circle

Comment: Yes, O is the center of the circumcircle of the triangle BHC.

Comment: (2) is not true. The correct version is  to prove that "Line MX  is perpendicular to the line XH"..

Comment: @Mick Could you please share some ideas in proving these statements? Thanks so much!

Comment: @user122049 It is a bit long in writing down the complete proof. For that reason, I will point out the provable facts leading to the solution only. If you have question about any one of them, please let me know. Also, give me some time to prepare.

Comment: This  is almost exactly a duplicate of [Triangle Geometry and Circles Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374719).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AD$ be the third altitude of $\triangle ABC$. Then, $DEF$ forms the pedal triangle which has the properties of having $H$ being its in-center. Therefore, $\theta = \theta_1$, for example. {Note: This part may not be necessary but I will leave it on for reference purpose.}

Extend $AD$ to cut the circle $BHC$ at $S$. Join $BS$ and $CS$. Then, $\alpha = \alpha_1 = \alpha_2$.

---

**Added:**  By the properties of the pedal $\triangle DEF$, $\alpha_3 = \alpha_4$.

[image]

WRT circle AFHE, $\alpha_3 = \alpha$.

WRT circle HDCE, $\alpha_4 = \alpha_1$.

WRT circle HBSC, $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$.

This makes $BACS$ a kite.

---

[image]
Therefore, $\omega = \omega_1$.

Construct $BT$//$AC$ cutting the circle $BHC$ at $T$. Join $CT$. All dark green shaded angles are equal. In addition, eventually, $\omega_1 = \omega_2$ (through subtended arcs). This means $BCTS$ is an isosceles trapezium with $BC$//$ST$. This proves $ABTC$ is a parallelogram with $AMT$ is a diagonal (i.e. $AMT$ is in fact a straight line.)

$DHXM$ is then cyclic because the purple shaded angles are all equal. This completes the proof of (2).

Then, $H$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle APM$. This completes the proof of (3).

For (1), we can argue in the following way:

a) Let $FE$ cut $AM$ at $U$. b) Draw $UV \bot PM$ and let it cut $PX$ at $W$.

So far we have fixed (i) two sides ($MP$ and $MU$); (ii) three points ($U$, $M$ and $P$); (iii) two possible altitudes ($UV$ and $PX$); and (iv) the possible orthocenter ($W$).

It is sufficient to claim (I) $PU$ is the third side of the triangle $MPU$; (II) For $\triangle MPU$, $PU$ and $PM$ are two of the adjacent legs with $PX$ being the included altitude; and (III) The three lines are concurrent at $P$.

Comment: Hi! Could please explain more indepth the proof of (1)? Thanks!

Comment: @Memat This was an answer posted several years ago. I need some time to recall what I have written.

Comment: @Memat See added. I have added some details to explain why $\omega = \omega_1$. If that is not what you are asking for, do let me know.