# Can somebody explain the last proof in this answer?

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

Can somebody explain to me in more detail the last proof ( for (1) ) of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2579686/1124189).

> For (1), we can argue in the following way:
>
> a) Let $FE$ cut $AM$ at $U$. b) Draw $UV \bot PM$ and let it cut $PX$
> at $W$.
>
> So far we have fixed (i) two sides ($MP$ and $MU$); (ii) three points
> ($U$, $M$ and $P$); (iii) two possible altitudes ($UV$ and $PX$); and
> (iv) the possible orthocenter ($W$).
>
> It is sufficient to claim (I) $PU$ is the third side of the triangle
> $MPU$; (II) For $\triangle MPU$, $PU$ and $PM$ are two of the adjacent
> legs with $PX$ being the included altitude; and (III) The three lines
> are concurrent at $P$.

Edit: in the meantime I found another way to proove the same thing using the radical center.

Comment: The answerer, @Mick, is fairly active here. You could/should comment on that answer to ask for clarification directly from the source.